# Eureka server taking long time to de-register the instance

Tags: java, spring, netflix-eureka

I am using netflix eureka server as discovery server. I want within 10 seconds if my client goes down, eureka server should detect it and should not return that instance as available service. Have tried below properties but nothing work. When I kill the client , it keep register till long time probalby 3-5 minute

```
eureka.instance.lease-expiration-duration-in-seconds=10
eureka.server.enable-self-preservation=false
eureka.server.response-cache-auto-expiration-in-seconds=10
eureka.server.renewal-percent-threshold=0.0
```

Please help my what could be the issue